# Repeating function insteading of calling function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to repeat a callback function on a click method within my javascript. All I want to do is reference the code from function() on. On my #previous and #next click methods, I don't want to call slideswitch. I want to run the code from line 4 on my code down. I realize I need to take out the function call for slideswitch, I just wanted to reference it for the discussion.

```
$holder.quicksand($filteredData, {
        duration: 800,
        easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
line 4      }, function() {
        $(".portfolioLink").click(function(){

        $(".inner-content.portfolio").show();

        clearInterval($('#slides').data('interval'));
        $("ul.pagination li").removeClass("current");

        var number = $(this).attr("data-id");

        var slideID = $(this).parent().attr("id");

        $("#previous").click(function() {
            slideID--;
            clearInterval($('#slides').data('interval'));
            $("ul.pagination li").removeClass("current");
            slideswitch(slideID);
        });

        $("#next").click(function() {
            slideID++;
            clearInterval($('#slides').data('interval'));
            $("ul.pagination li").removeClass("current");
            slideswitch(slideID);
        });
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Create a named function instead of an anonymous function, pass the function to the slider.

Comment: So it would be $holder.quicksand($filteredData, {
        duration: 800,
        easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
line 4      }, myFunction()

Are you referring to that?

Comment: No, it would be `$holder.quicksand($filteredData, { duration: 800, easing: 'easeInOutQuad' line 4 }, myFunction)`

Comment: Recall that functions don't have to be anonymous - they can have *names*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$holder.quicksand($filteredData, {
        duration: 800,
        easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
}, myFunction);
```

And your function definition (there are some problems with your code so this might not be structured correctly:

```
function myFunction() {
    $(".portfolioLink").click(function(){ // where is this supposed to end?

    $(".inner-content.portfolio").show();

    clearInterval($('#slides').data('interval'));
    $("ul.pagination li").removeClass("current");

    var number = $(this).attr("data-id");

    var slideID = $(this).parent().attr("id");

    $("#previous").click(function() {
        slideID--;
        clearInterval($('#slides').data('interval'));
        $("ul.pagination li").removeClass("current");
        slideswitch(slideID);
    });

    $("#next").click(function() {
        slideID++;
        clearInterval($('#slides').data('interval'));
        $("ul.pagination li").removeClass("current");
        slideswitch(slideID);
    });
}
```

Also, you shouldn't be binding events in a function you plan on calling multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for the input on the code. I'm fixing it now. I'll post my results shortly.

Comment: I didn't realize that I could call functions like that. My javascript knowledge +1

Comment: You're not actually calling it, you're just passing it as the callback function for quicksand.